# Python: create matrix from function and arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I'm sure this has been asked before but I couldn't find the solution (also there must be a better title for this question - suggestions welcome). Is there a faster way of doing something like the following? I would like to map array elements to matrix through a function.

```
a = np.random.rand(100)
b = np.random.rand(100)
c = 5

matrix = np.zeros((100, 100))
for i in range(100):
    for j in range(100):
        matrix[i, j] = function(a[i], b[j], c)
```

I tried this but doesn't work:

```
matrix = np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: function(a[i], b[j], c), (100, 100), dtype=float) # Doesn't work
```

Neither does this:

```
vfunction = np.vectorize(function)
matrix = vfunction(a, b, c) # Doesn't work
```

Comment: Found a related solution that leverages this function: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html

Comment: Can you shed some light on `function`? Is this really a non-vectorisable operation?

Comment: The function I'm using is "return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-(a + b + c)))" it just takes in 3 numbers. The vectorised function doesn't give me the matrix I want.

Comment: `np.exp` works with an array.  What you need to do is figure out how to calculate `a+b+c` from the whole arrays, not just their elements.  Without any further fiddling that expression produces a (100,) array that matches the common shapes of `a` and `b`.  Think `broadcasting`.

Comment: Currently using: `a_ = np.tile(a, (100, 1)).T`; `b_ = np.tile(b, (100, 1))`; `matrix = function(a_, b_, c)`. This works, I'm not sure how to do better.

Comment: You probably won't do better. This is fully vectorized.